# Angular2 allow only predefined query params

Tags: angular

I want to allow predefined query parameters before components load. For example I defined allowed parameters in array

```
let params = ['status', 'category'];
```

Redirect url is

```
let url='http://example.com/products?status=1&category=2'
```

I want to forbid another query parameter before redirect. What is the best method for example guard, resolver or etc.

Comment: This question is opinion-based. It is most likely being closed. There are different ways to solve it though. You could use a guard. You could also do checks in using angular life cycle hooks.

Comment: Can you give an example? How can I do?

Comment: [Check the documentation here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). But basically you would extract the routes parameters and depending on what they are grant access or deny the request and redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for guards can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

As a general idea:

1. Implement the guard.
2. Extract the routes parameters
3. Do your own manual checking
4. Depending on your result return true for a valid request and false for an invalid request

If false is being returned the routing is aborted immediately and a user will not be able to navigate to the selected route.